# Android Dual Pane - Going From Details To List

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have followed the official documentation http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/tablets-and-handsets.html  for Tablet support to create dual pane layout that works as shown below, in that in small screens (phones) it uses one Fragment inside one Activity to display a list of objects and another fragment inside another Activity.

[image: Android Dual Pane Layout]

Every other documentation I read talks about a one way flow from Master to details, now I want to go back the other way, from details to master and I am stuck.

In the details, I have added an Item that  I want to display in the list and I want this to be dynamic such that I can add few items and each time I hit save I want the List to grow.

This is what I have done so far

In FragmentA(List Fragment) I have a method that (re)loads the data and call notifyDataSetChanged on the adapter.
I added a method in the call back that is called each time an item is added. And both Activity A and Activity B implements this listener
So when I add an item in FragmentB(Details Fragment) I call the listener and on Activity A which is housing the dual pane layout I try this

```
  public void OnNewCustomerAdded() {
        Fragment frag = null;
        frag = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("CustomertListFragment");
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.detach(frag);
        ft.attach(frag);
        ft.commit();      

    }
```

Unfortunately that throws a NPE, and also if I call the methods directly in the Fragment to reload data, that throws an NPE. The only thing that works with some side effects is this

```
  public void OnNewClientAdded() {
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

So how can I safely restart a Fragment inside an Activity without restarting the other Fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, this is quite tricky, never expected it to be this challenging. Well this is how I solve it.

First I removed the second activity and reworked the code to show single pane in handheld devices and dual pane in tablets using just one Activity instead of two. This is not necessary but it helps when you are dealing with one set of lifecycles and listeners.

Then to actually have items added in the DetailsFragment appear immediately in the ListFragment while still having the Details Fragment open. I finished the containing Activity, restarted it and passed it an intent that tells it to start up the DetailsFragment

Remember that the ListFragment is set to start up no matter which device size. So you just need to start the DetailsFragment and since there is already a call back that does that it makes it easy so here is the code

```
//Callback method for when an item is added, called from the Details 
   //Fragment
   public void OnNewCustomerAdded() {
        Intent mIntent = getIntent();
        mIntent.putExtra(Constants.SHOULD_START_CUSTOMER_DETAILS, true);
        finish();
        startActivity(mIntent);
      }
```

Then in the onCreate of the Activity, after the ListFragment has been started, you do this

```
boolean shouldStartCustomerDetails = getIntent().getBooleanExtra(Constants.SHOULD_START_CLIENT_DETAILS, false);
        if (shouldStartClientDetails){
            OnCustomerListItemSelected(0);
        }
```

The OnCustomertListItemSelected is the standard mCallback listener that you get if you created a Master/Details Activity in Android Studio, I just modified it to suit my app like so

```
 /**
     * Callback method from {@link OnCustomerListItemSelectedListener}
     * indicating that the item with the given ID was selected.
     */
    @Override
    public void OnCustomerListItemSelected(long id) {
        if (mTwoPane) {
            // In two-pane mode, show the detail view in this activity by
            // adding or replacing the detail fragment using a
            // fragment transaction.
            CustomerDetailsFragment fragment = CustomerDetailsFragment.newInstance(id);
                     getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.customeractivity_detail_container, fragment)
                    .commit();

        } else {
            // In single-pane mode, simply start the detail activity
            // for the selected item ID.
            CustomerDetailsFragment fragment =
                    CustomerDetailsFragment.newInstance(getIntent().getLongExtra(Constants.ARG_ITEM_ID, 0));
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.customeractivity_list_container, fragment)
                    .commit();

        }
    }
```